# Compare dates from two queries PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have two queries , the first gets some data back from my table, the second query displays all half hour times between two specified dates. Is there a way of comparing the date results from query 1 from query 2 and merge the two results together when the date from query 2 doesn't exist in query 1 result.

I'll attach a little diagram to show what I mean.
[image]

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
reading_date, 
reading_value    
FROM DCM_READING
WHERE reading_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('17-NOV-2019' || ' 000000', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS')
AND  TO_DATE('19-NOV-2019'   || ' 235959', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS')
ORDER BY reading_date;
```

Query 2:

```
  select TO_DATE('17-NOV-2019' || ' 000000', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS') + 
         ( level / 48 ) dt
from   dual
connect by level <= ( 48 + ( 48 * 
    (  TO_DATE('19-NOV-2019' || ' 000000', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS') - 
         TO_DATE('17-NOV-2019' || ' 000000', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MISS') )
  ) 
) ;
```

Comment: Every hear of the Y2k bug?  I don't know if '18-Nov-19' is November 18, 2019, or 19 November 2018'  Ok I can infer it from your actual code, but then that just highlights the fact that your dates are stored as strings instead of DATEs.  Yet another design flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the timestamps you want in a CTE, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
with cte (reading_date) as (
    select date '2020-11-17' from dual
    union all
    select reading_date + interval '30' minute 
    from cte 
    where reading_date + interval '30' minute < date '2020-11-19'
)
select c.reading_date, d.reading_value
from cte c
left join dcm_reading d on d.reading_date = c.reading_date
order by c.reading_date
```

I like to use recursive queries rather than Oracle specific `connect by` syntax, because they are standard SQL - but that's mostly a matter of taste, the logic remains the same.

Comment: This is definitely looking more like what I had in my head - only all values for all time periods are NULL i.e. - the d.reading_value doesn't persist in the final outcome.

Comment: @elszeus: that would mean that there is no data in `dcm_reading` for the dates that are generated by the cte.

Comment: Yup, youre right - I put in the wrong date!! 
and thank you also, I didn't realise connect by could achieve the same thing!